# Machine name resolves to wrong IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, dhcp, domain-name-system

I have a machine called server1 (windows server 2008). It was initially set to have an automatically assigned IP by the DHCP server (windows server 2008). It assigned it 192.168.0.180. I changed server1 to have a static ip of 192.168.0.60. I then deleted the reservation out of the DHCP server. On my local dev machine (windows 7) when I try to ping it it resolves to the old 192.168.0.180 address. I've tried `ipconfig /flushdns' on all the machines, and I've tried rebooting etc. From server1 when I ping it by its name it resolves properly, just not from anywhere else. Is there some cache somewhere that needs to be cleared?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's like the WINS/NETBIOS resolution is getting cached. I've been trying `nbtstat` and `arp` to clear it, but not sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: `ipconfig /registerdns`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That doesn't seem to be working. Also if I run `ipconfig /displaynds` there's no entry for `server1`.

Comment: Cached result in the DC possibly? -- EDIT: Can you directly ping the fixed IP, and it's just the "Server1" failing to resolve or is the server inaccessible entirely?

Comment: I don't have a DC setup.

Comment: You deleted DNS entry & WINS (on the server)?

Comment: on the server I'm trying to ping or the one I'm trying to ping from?

Answer (score 2):

Is that DHCP server also running as a DNS server? If so, clean up the host entry in DNS (delete and/or clear cache).

**Update, 20120219**

From an other post you made "[Can't find computer by name only by IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/253363/cant-find-computer-by-name-only-by-ip-address)", I make up you do not have any internal naming resolution (like DNS, WINS or host-files).

My advice? Unless you want to return here every other month with resolving issues, get an internal DNS ASAP!

Comment: It's not. Just a DHCP server. We're not running an internal DNS server.

Comment: Just to be sure: the IP is not in the hosts-file either?

Comment: Yeah, no IP on hosts file. Did setup a WINS server (on same DHCP server). Will setup DNS on it also.

Comment: So... is your question answered then? Please accept my answer if it is.

Comment: Nope. Still no solution,